# How should I handle NDsolve in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

```
delta = -0.823
g = 0.000005

sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {a'[t] == -I*a[t] (delta + g*Re[b[t]]) - a[t]*0.04 /2, 
     b'[t] == -I (b[t]*delta + g*Abs[a[t]]^2) - a[t]*0.09/2, 
     a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1}, 
    {a, b}, {t, 0, 200}]
ParametricPlot[{Re[b'[t]], Re[b[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, 200}]
```

I wish to use `Manipulate` to control the value of `delta` and `g`, but don't know how to handle the output from `NDsolve` when doing dynamic plotting. Can someone give me some guidance on `Manipulate`?

Comment: Try `Manipulate[sol=NDSolve[...];ParametricPlot[...],{delta,-1,0},{g,0,0.0005}]` and see what you get.

Comment: @Bill It returns "0 cannot used as a variable". I tried to change the values to {-0.923,-0,823} and it returns "0.923 cannot used as a variable" now.

Comment: @Bill Thank you! I had already solved the problem by adding ```Clear``` before the codes. You are right, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -I*a[t] (delta + g*Re[b[t]]) - a[t]*0.04/2, 
    b'[t] == -I (b[t]*delta + g*Abs[a[t]]^2) - a[t]*0.09/2, a[0] == 1,
     b[0] == 1}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 200}];
 ParametricPlot[{Re[b'[t]], Re[b[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, 200}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {g, 0.000001, 
  0.00001}, {delta, -0.823 - 0.01, -0.823 + 0.01}]
```

Comment: Maybe add `TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate` to keep it from an extraneous update after `sol` is changed (during an update in which a control is changed), though on a human scale, the MWE is fast enough as is.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the following variant of cvgmtj's answer. It has some performance advantages.

```
Manipulate[
  {aF, adF, bF, bdF} =
    NDSolveValue[
      {a'[t] == -I*a[t] (delta + g*Re[b[t]]) - a[t]*0.04/2, 
       b'[t] == -I (b[t]*delta + g*Abs[a[t]]^2) - a[t]*0.09/2, a[0] == 1,
       b[0] == 1}, 
     {a, a', b, b'}, {t, 0, 200}];
  ParametricPlot[{Re[bdF[t]], Re[bF[t]]}, {t, 0, 200}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
  {aF, None},
  {adF, None},
  {bF, None},
  {bdF, None},
  {g, 0., 0.0005, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {delta, -0.823 - 0.25, -0.823 + 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  TrackedSymbols :> {g, delta}]
```

[image: manip1]

I might not have posted this variant because the performance improvement is not all that noticeable, except that I want you to bring a further variant, which eliminates `g`, to your attention. I can see no visible difference in the plot produced from the following code form the plot produced by the preceding code. Can you?

```
Manipulate[
  {aF, adF, bF, bdF} =
    NDSolveValue[
      {a'[t] == -I*a[t] delta - a[t]*0.04/2, 
       b'[t] == -I b[t] delta - a[t]*0.09/2,
       a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1}, 
      {a, a', b, b'}, {t, 0, 200}];
  ParametricPlot[{Re[bdF[t]], Re[bF[t]]}, {t, 0, 200}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
  {aF, None},
  {adF, None},
  {bF, None},
  {bdF, None},
  {delta, -0.823 - 0.25, -0.823 + 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  TrackedSymbols :> {delta}]
```

[image: manip2]

Makes me wonder if `g` is actually a significant variable. Perhaps your mathematical model can be profitably simplified were you to eliminate `g`.

Comment: Thank you m_goldberg! The g in this equation is the most important term which represents coupling efficiency. The reason it has not much impact in the figure is the span range not big enough. A BIG thanks for your help! And also could u give me some suggestions on how to find more examples about ```manipulate```?

Comment: @BenXylona. Searching on the tag ***manipulate*** on this site should give you lots of examples.

Comment: @BenXylona. I added the tag ***manipulate** to your question. All you have do see more  than a thousand examples is to click on that tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[reParametricListLinePlot];

reParametricListLinePlot[
   ifs : {_InterpolatingFunction, _InterpolatingFunction}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern@ListLinePlot] := 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[Re@#@"ValuesOnGrid" & /@ ifs], opts];

Manipulate[
 reParametricListLinePlot[
  NDSolveValue[
   {a'[t] == -I*a[t] (delta + g*Re[b[t]]) - a[t]*0.04/2,
    b'[t] == -I (b[t]*delta + g*Abs[a[t]]^2) - a[t]*0.09/2,
    a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1},
   {b', b}, {t, 0, 200}],
  InterpolationOrder -> 3, AspectRatio -> 1],
 {{delta, -0.823}, -2, -0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{g, 0.000005}, 0.000001, 0.0001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]